# Union statement statement in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have multiple large csv files that I want to merge and store the final table in a database for using in Pandas in the future. I read them all using Pandas and store them as separate but similar tables into a Sqlite database.

I want to merge the rows (vertically) by a SQL string and then use them in pandas for more analyses. I was wondering if this is a good practice to go back and forth between pandas and SQL for when we deal with large files and have limited memory (16GB) ?

Also my code gives me an error and I was unsure if there is a syntax issue or something more significant that I missing here.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\master.db', echo=False)
string = text("""SELECT * INTO Flows FROM (select * from "f2007-08" UNION select * from "f2009-10")""")
engine.execute(string)
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO Flows SELECT ...` is the correct syntax to insert into a table using the results of a query.

Comment: I removed the `*` bur received the same error:

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "INTO": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT INTO Flows FROM (select * from "f2007-08" UNION select * from "f2009-10")]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

Comment: Has nothing to do with the `*`. Your entire syntax is wrong.

Comment: It's not `SELECT INTO`, it's `INSERT INTO xxx SELECT`.

Comment: [sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for inserting the results of a query into another table.

It's `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT ...`

```
string = text("""
    INSERT INTO Flows 
    select * from "f2007-08" 
    UNION 
    select * from "f2009-10" 
""")
```